# Where do flies go?

Tags: zoology, entomology

Where are flies attracted most? Apart from food odours, of course. Why do they seem to be attracted by hot and humid places? Do they prefer shades or light? Why do they tend to get inside very easily?

Answer (score 1):

As far as getting inside, they are small, and they can get in through openings you don't notice, or just sneak in when you open the door.

Comment: It's more of a comment.